# Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider appHostConfig is not supported

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy, msdeploy

I am trying to do automatic deployment with MSDeploy but once I changed to using the app pool I received the following error:

```
Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider appHostConfig is not supported.
```

When deploying I need to specify the Application Pool Name to use. The server is 64 bit.

MSBuild

```
"%SOAB_MSBUILD_EXE%" "%SOAB_LOCAL_APP_PATH%\WebAPI\WebAPI.csproj" /t:Package /p:Configuration=Debug;PublishProfile=CI /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /p:IncludeIisSettings=true /p:IncludeAppPool=true
```

MSDeploy

```
CALL "%SOAB_LOCAL_APP_PATH%\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\WebAPI.deploy.cmd" /Y "-setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='Default Web Site\WebAPI'" "-setParam:'IIS Web Application Pool Name'='MyAppPool'"
```

MSBuild Path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe
```

Anything wrapped in %% are variables replaced at runtime by the build server.

Everything was working as expected until I tried to get the ApplicationPool to change using MSDeploy. To get the application pool to work I added the following parameters to the MSBuild command `/p:IncludeIisSettings=true /p:IncludeAppPool=true` and included the setParam name/value to the MSDeploy command. I cannot use the DefaultAppPool. Any help is appreciated as to what I am doing wrong, thank you in advance.

Edit: WebAPI.SetParameters.xml Parameters Declared in obj\debug\package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/WebAPI_deploy" />
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Pool Name" value="DefaultAppPool" />
  <setParameter name="IisVirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath" value="c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI_deploy" />
</parameters>
```

Edit: Verbose Log, I dont think this adds much value but maybe it will help someone who has more experience with MSDeploy.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\WebAPI.zip' -dest:auto,includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\WebAPI.SetParameters.xml" -setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='Default Web Site\WebAPI' -setParam:'IIS Web Application Pool Name'='MyAppPool' -verbose
Verbose: Performing synchronization pass #1.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to 'appHostConfig/Default Web Site/WebAPI' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'contentPath/c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/3' could not be applied anywhere.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to 'appHostConfig/Default Web Site/WebAPI' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'contentPath/c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/3' could not be applied anywhere.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to 'appHostConfig/Default Web Site/WebAPI' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'contentPath/c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/3' could not be applied anywhere.
Verbose: No backup was executed.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to 'appHostConfig/Default Web Site/WebAPI' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'contentPath/c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/3' could not be applied anywhere.
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/1' is applicable to 'appHostConfig/Default Web Site/WebAPI' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/2' is applicable to 'contentPath/c:\_Files\MyApplication\WebAPI\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp' because of its scope.
Verbose: Parameter entry 'IIS Web Application Name/3' could not be applied anywhere.
ERROR: Error: Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider appHostConfig is not supported.
ERROR: Error count: 1.
```

Comment: I would like to get this working but overall are there any alternatives for deploying to IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the original post I tried uninstalling Web Deploy, and installing the 64 bit version. For some reason installing the 64 bit version of Web Deploy also installed the 32 bit version. My team had multiple versions installed on the server. I finally removed all registry entries, and completely removed everything related to Web Deploy including the services. I reinstalled the 64 bit version of Web Deploy (Complete Install with Services), and received the same error message. I checked both 'Program Files' & 'Program Files x86' and saw Web Deploy in both. I switched from using WebAPI.deploy.cmd to MSDeploy.exe directly. The reason why is because the WebAPI.deploy.cmd file was still using the 32 bit version of Web Deploy. By changing to using MSDeploy.exe directly, I was able to control which version 32 or 64 bit. I received a new error, and resolved it. All I need now is to insert the password for the app pool identity.

Answer (score 1):

Error says the problem. You have to use the `64-bit` version on the source and the `64-bit` version on the destination.

You are using `Microsoft Visual Studio` `32-bit` version. There for you have to install `64-bit` of `Microsoft Visual Studio`. Then everything will work fine. And also make sure your `Microsoft Web Deploy` also `64-bit` version.

---

**Alternative method -:** In other hand this error occur because `appHostConfig` sync between the source and destination. There for follow this command to ignore the error.

```
-skip:attributes.name="AppWarmupModule"
```

**In MSdeploy `-skip:<arg settings>` keyword's main task is specify mentioned object to skip during synchronization**.

Comment: I couldn't find a 64 bit version of visual studio, see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/517541/vs-2019-downloaded-x64-version-installed-x86.html

Comment: It seems `VS` can run also as 64-bit version also. Then what about Microsoft web deploy, download 64-bit version of that also.

Comment: Did you try Alternative method which I have mentioned

Comment: I did reinstall web deploy to a 64 bit version but received the same error as in the original post. Trying the alternative method now.

Comment: I tried the alternative method, and it fails. I get the same error message.

Comment: I believe the issue is that I have both 32 & 64 bit versions of web deploy installed. Looking at the registry for the MSDeploy path, I see the path for both versions. Trying to verify now... I uninstalled web deploy before installing the 64 bit version which is awkward. Looks like someone already had both versions installed and the installer removed the 64 bit version during uninstallation, and the .deploy.cmd script can't properly determine which version to use.

Comment: And also take a look at this blog -> http://jalukadev.blogspot.com/2013/09/web-deploy-command-line-msdeployexe.html

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because you helped me alot by the resource, and by hinting that it was definitely a versioning issue. Thank You!!!

Comment: I saw `Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider appHostConfig is not supported` error occur because of several issues and they all have different solution. According to your answer I think you have found solution by own. This will definitely help other users who will have the same issue in future. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Everything was working fine, no changes were made to MSDeploy or anything, but the msdeploy sync simply stopped working one day, after working fine for over a year.

Running the command:

> "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:webServer -dest:auto,computerName=[DestinationServer]

Started failing with the error message:

> An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
>
> Using a 64-bit source and a 32-bit destination with provider webServer is not supported.

The solution was simply to restart the destination Windows server. We recently installed Windows updates, so I'm guessing there was a pending or half-installed update that had the system in a weird state.